# Django - Trying to alter the order of results when doing an Order By

Tags: python, sql, django

Coming from SQL I know how to do the following extremely easily -

```
SELECT TOP 10 jobmst_owner, COUNT(jobmst_owner) AS jobmst_count FROM jobmst
GROUP BY jobmst_owner
ORDER BY COUNT(jobmst_owner) DESC
```

This gives me the Top 10 of what I'm counting but most importantly it's putting the jobmst_owner first like so -

```
jobmst_owner, COUNT(jobmst_owner)
213, 6536
234, 2356
63, 1235
65, 1100
543, 1000
2353, 923
135, 345
5, 222
23, 123
34, 110
```

My Django query is doing the opposite putting the count first which I don't want.

```
resultsford3 = Jobmst.objects.values('jobmst_owner').annotate(num_jobs=Count('jobmst_id')).order_by('-num_jobs')[:10]
```

So what am I doing wrong? I don't want it to look like this -

```
COUNT(jobmst_owner), jobmst_owner
6536, 213
2356, 234
1235, 63
1100, 65
1000, 543
923, 2353
345, 135
222, 5
123, 23
110, 34
```

Added bonus,

If someone can explain me how to join 2 columns together so I can actually get the following SQL query in Django -

```
SELECT TOP 10 owner_name, COUNT(jobmst_owner) AS jobmst_count FROM jobmst
INNER JOIN owner ON jobmst.jobmst_owner = owner.owner_id
GROUP BY owner_name
ORDER BY COUNT(jobmst_owner) DESC
```

Again, I want the owner_name first and then the Count.

Here are the 2 models.py listings -

```
class Jobmst(models.Model):
    jobmst_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    jobmst_type = models.SmallIntegerField()
    jobmst_prntid = models.IntegerField('self', null=True, blank=True)
    jobmst_active = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    evntmst_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    jobmst_evntoffset = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    jobmst_name = models.TextField(blank=True)
    jobmst_mode = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    jobmst_owner = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    jobmst_desc = models.TextField(blank=True) # This field type is a guess.
    jobmst_crttm = models.DateTimeField()
    jobdtl_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    jobmst_lstchgtm = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    jobmst_runbook = models.TextField(blank=True) # This field type is a guess.
    jobcls_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    jobmst_prntname = models.TextField(blank=True)
    jobmst_alias = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    jobmst_dirty = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.jobmst_name   
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'jobmst'

class Owner(models.Model):
    owner_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    owner_type = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    owner_allagents = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.owner_name   
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'owner'
```

Legacy DB so please don't ask me to explain their horrible DB design.

**ANSWER BELOW!  Thanks to Peter.  It seems I'm going to be hitting my head against the wall with this legacy DB ;P**

Got the answer and it was related to this #@#$%@# legacy database :)

I had to modify my models.py -

```
class Jobmst(models.Model):
    jobmst_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    jobmst_type = models.SmallIntegerField()
    jobmst_prntid = models.IntegerField('self', null=True, blank=True)
    jobmst_active = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    evntmst_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    jobmst_evntoffset = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    jobmst_name = models.TextField(blank=True)
    jobmst_mode = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    jobmst_owner = models.ForeignKey('Owner', db_column='jobmst_owner', related_name = 'Jobmst_Jobmst_owner', blank=True, null=True)
    jobmst_desc = models.TextField(blank=True) # This field type is a guess.
    jobmst_crttm = models.DateTimeField()
    jobdtl_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    jobmst_lstchgtm = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    jobmst_runbook = models.TextField(blank=True) # This field type is a guess.
    jobcls_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    jobmst_prntname = models.TextField(blank=True)
    jobmst_alias = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    jobmst_dirty = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.jobmst_name   
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'jobmst'
```

To have a correct ForeignKey mapping.

After that used the query provided gracefully by Peter DeGlopper (with a minor tweak) and success!

```
resultsford3 = Owner.objects.values('owner_name').annotate(num_jobs=Count('Jobmst_Jobmst_owner')).order_by('-num_jobs')[:10]
```

Comment: What do you mean "putting the count first"? The `.values()` method returns a list of dictionaries, which don't have a well-defined order as far as their contents go.

Comment: Basically with the SQL query the results come as follows -

jobmst_owner, COUNT(jobmst_id)

My django query the results are coming back as

COUNT(jobmst_id), jobmst_owner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the question on joining two columns together - even with a legacy database, you can turn autodiscovered integer columns into foreign keys:

```
owner = ForeignKey(Owner, db_column='jobmst_owner')
```

Based on your clarification of my reading of your SQL query, I think that's actually straighforward once the FK relationship is know:

```
Owner.objects.values('owner_name').annotate(num_jobs=Count('jobmst')).order_by('-num_jobs')[:10]
```

As voithos notes, the results of that QS are not inherently ordered. I don't think the `annotate` grouping behavior works with a `values_list` query, which is the main way to get ordered results from a Django queryset, but you can trivially create them:

```
owners_qs = Owner.objects.values... # as above
owners_with_counts = ((owner.owner_name, owner.num_jobs) for owner in owners_qs)
```

Comment: Close but no cigar.  You're on the right track with part 2.  This gives me the owner_name but I want it to reference against the jobmst table.

I want the count of the jobmst table grouped by jobmst_owner but I want to use the PK/FK link with the owner table to get it to return the owner_name instead of the jobmst_owner ID.

ie. jobmst.jobmst_owner = owner.owner_id

Comment: So the result should be for each owner name, how many jobs have that owner? Edited to produce that, or at least I think so.

Comment: Each owner has a different count as per my updated question.  The query you provided is only against the one table with is "Owner" which has a 1 to 1 relation between owner_name and owner_id.  I want to query the owner_name against the results from jobmst where there are many.  hmmm... think I just answered myself a bit.  I'm going to google django one to many relationships and see what comes up.

Comment: The annotate should pull in the join, since it's being asked to count a reverse FK. Unless I'm just spacing out. Have you tested its results and gotten something wrong (a possibility, I admit) or does it just not look like it'll do the right thing?

Comment: You got the answer Peter but I had some tweaking to do information posted in my original question!

Comment: I'm curious - what happened to make you have to explicitly set the related name? Normally you can do reverse lookups using the name of the related class.

Comment: If you're referring to having to explicitly put Jobmst_Jobmst_Owner I'm not sure.  without letting it know the table it was complaining about a relationship missing.